# Array sort en Java

Tags: java

Estaba en Processing cuendo me encotré con este problema:

En Javascript hay una función "sort()" para los arrays.
A esta función se le pueden especificar parámetros, pudiendo crear por ejemplo:

`array.sort((a, b) => b - a);`
o`array.sort((a, b) => b - 2 * a);`

Sé que en Java existe un método para ordenar arrays, pero no puedes ponerle los parámetros que Javascript deja.

La solución a este problema es sencilla de resolver, pero más correcta si de alguna manera se pudiese pasar la función como parámetro.

La solución que he hecho (en respuestas) ha sido una función "ordenar()" con 3 o 4 parámetros con unas limitaciones muy claras (solo 1 operación que pasa por un caracter, solo funciona para un array de Int). Debido a eso, cualquier respuesta que sea válida y consiga solucionar mis problemas será marcada como válida.

Comment: Iba ha hacer un pregunta- respuesta, ya que da la opción, pero ha salido un error y he tenido que poner la respuesta a parte :(

La pregunta es si existe alguna manera de hacer el código que está bien, mejor

Comment: Creo que no me he explicado bien cuando he dicho el comentario anterior, quería decir que si hay alguna manera de solucionar los "problemas" que tienen mi código. (No son realmente problemas, ya que las funciones que he creado sirven como solución, pero siempre que haya otra solución mejor a la mía, la votare hacia arriba y la daré como aceptada)

Comment: Lo digo en otras palabras, la pregunta no está clara. Por favor revisa cómo la has redactado y si lo amerita que mejores la redaccíón o agregues información, edítala. Por otro lado, como mencionas JavaScript como referencia pero en realidad la pregunta se refiere a Java, considero que no se debería incluir [tag:javascript]

Comment: Entendido, ahora lo cambio

Comment: Espero que no haya ningún problema, si sigue habiendo errores a tu parecer, edítalos, por favor.

Comment: Processing es una librería de Java en la que no hace falta que pongas todo eso de public static... usar main

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, pues dejo el hilo para los que si saben de Java :) Voy a eliminar mis comentarios previos pues me parece que ya no son necesarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He intentado crear ese sort para java y aunque solo funciona para arrays int[] y solo admite los operadores <+, -, *, />, permite que la función se haga de forma inversa.

Empecé preguntándome si se podría hacer con alguna librería, y con algunas matemáticas de java (importando para operaciones de Math.signum(x)) pero veo que ha sido mucho más sencillo.

Para usar la función tan solo hay que usar ordenar(array_a_ordenar, *operación entre comillas únicas: ' '*, *true si queremos que se ordene al revés*).

Este es el código que he usado:

```java
int Signo(int a) {
  if (a > 0) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a < 0) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
//
//
void ordenar(int[] array, char operador, boolean reverso) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      int n = 0;
      int a = array[i];
      int b = array[i+1];
      if (operador == '+') {
        n = Signo(a+b);
      } else if (operador == '-') {
        n = Signo(a-b);
      } else if (operador == '*') {
        n = Signo(a*b);
      } else if (operador == '/' || operador == ':') {
        n = Signo(a/b);
      } else {
        println("La función de ordenar arrays solo soporta estas operaciones: Suma, resta, multiplicación, división");
      }
      if (reverso == true) {
        n *= -1;
      }
      if (n > 0) {
        cambiarInt(array, i, i+1);
      }
    }
  }
}
//
//
void ordenar(int[] array, char operador) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < array.length - j - 1; j++) {
      int n = 0;
      int a = array[j];
      int b = array[j+1];
      if (operador == '+') {
        n = Signo(a+b);
      } else if (operador == '-') {
        n = Signo(a-b);
      } else if (operador == '*') {
        n = Signo(a*b);
      } else if (operador == '/' || operador == ':') {
        n = Signo(a/b);
      } else {
        println("La función de ordenar arrays solo soporta estas operaciones: Suma, resta, multiplicación, división");
      }
      if (n > 0) {
        cambiarInt(array, j, j+1);
      }
    }
  }
}
//
//
void cambiarInt(int[] array, int a, int b) {
  int temporal = array[a];
  array[a] = array[b];
  array[b] = temporal;
}
```

Comment: No me dejaba usarlo entre las comillas hacia atrás ``. Me salía error, pero no me decía de que

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, no había caído en eso.

Comment: Editado un error en cambiarInt(), ya que los "a" y "b" que estaba enviando hacia cambiarInt() eran valores y no índices

Comment: He eliminado mis comentarios previos pues me parece que ya no son necesarios.